# Use Genexis Platinum 4410 as wired extender

Tags: router, wifi-configuration, wired-networking

I want to use my extra [Genexis Platinum 4410](https://genexis.eu/product/platinum) as wired extender. I've checked the whole internet and found a few solutions but nothing seems to work.

- The WiFi blinks Blue.
- GE lights Blue(because I've connected the Ethernet cable to GE port).
- LOS blinks Red.
- Power lights Blue.

Hardware Version: V2.1

Software Version: P4410-V2-1.24

Please help me solve this issue. My D-Link router have a straight forward interface but interface of Genexis is too complicated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's a "wired extender"? Do you mean you want it to work as an AP with wired connection to another router so you can extend the Wi-Fi network?

Comment: Oh yes - please don't reply in a comment, rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1770531/edit) the question. That helps to focus it and keeps it up-to-date, and keeps the relevant info readily available. Knowing your D-Link router model would also help, as well as links to the manuals; and specifying which ports are connected. GE stands for Gigabit Ethernet, but at least I've no clue what's "LOS" or what the LED colors or blinking patterns mean.

Comment: Your device is overkill for the task. A simple and inexpensive WiFi range extender with Ethernet port(s) would do the job nice a easy. The Genexis residential gateway can theoretically do the same but that depends on its firmware having the option to act as well as a range extender. While technically possible - it has the hardware for it and an absurdly lot more - the software must have been written to allow such usage and that's not a given.

Comment: Yes like u mentioned @Peregrino69. I want to connect this to another router (which will the main) and use this to extend the WiFi network.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I didn't buy this device. This was an extra that I have. So I thought about using extra router like this.

Comment: You need to read your user's manual that should describe all the settings available in the firmware. What you're looking for is how to set it in "bridge", "WiFi extender" or similar mode.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yea but there isn't any user manual with this device and neither could I find any online.

Comment: Really? https://genexis.eu/product/platinum/downloads where you can find an installation guide that unfortunately has no mention of the feature you want. However, the guide seems too succinct for such a powerful and multi-purpose device. As such, again, *what you're looking for is how to set it in "bridge", "WiFi extender" or similar mode* and finding it out on the firmware settings is your homework. If there's no such settings then assume it can't be used  for the setup you want, something not really unexpected as commented before. A US$15 repeater WILL do what you want.